# “Correlative poetry” — как перевести это название на русский?

Tags: перевод, терминология

Есть особенная разновидность поэтического творчества, которую я сейчас опишу. По-английски этот жанр называется “correlative poetry”; мне хотелось бы знать русское название.

Есть несколько кортежей из слов (в математическом смысле слова: кортеж — это конечный упорядоченный список заданной длины), и в каждом кортеже на каждой позиции слово играет семантическую роль, заданную номером позиции. Кортежи разнесены по строкам стихотворения (необязательно по всем строкам), и в каждой такой строке слова встречаются в той же последовательности, в которой они записаны в кортеж. Получается занятный эффект «соотносения», похожий на взаимосвязанности в численных отношениях (А относится к Б, как В относится к Г — то есть частное А/Б равно частному В/Г, и отсюда следует, что частное А/В равно частному Б/Г).

Пример такого стихотворения можно найти [здесь](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2857099?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents). В оригинале (в испанском, а разъяснения — по-английски) это сонет; ниже я приведу подстрочный перевод. В данном случае кортежи — это тройки; первое слово каждой тройки относится к зверю, второе — к птице, а третье — к рыбе. Первая тройка — это среда обитания; вторая тройка — это, собственно, название существа и его способ передвижения; третья тройка — это место, которое существу приносит радость; а четвёртая — это условия, в которых обитает существо и которые оно покидает.

Мой вопрос относится не к литературному приёму (довольно-таки специфическому), а к стихам, которые использованием такого приёма характеризуются. Стихи эти могут быть более или менее осмыслены, предназначаться для выражения одного или другого, но их основная черта и, можно сказать, цель существования — организация именно в такой форме, которую я описал. Слово «сонет» — того же рода: стихотворение, нарушающее определённые формальные требования (рифмовка, распределение мысли) перестаёт быть сонетом, чем бы оно ни было сверх того. Разве что вот эта форма — более специальная и более «игривая».

Вот подстрочник:

```
    Ни в этих лесах (А1), ни в этих небесах (А2), ни в этой реке (А3)
не бежит зверь (Б1), не летит птица (Б2), рыба не плывёт (Б3),
которые не выслушают с полным вниманием
грустный голос моих грустных рыданий;

    и хотя бы даже и в расцвете лета
моя жалоба будет ветру доверена,
когда каждому из них милей всего их
свежая пещера (В1), зелёное дерево (В2), прохладный ручей (В3),

    сочувствием движимы к моей жалобе,
оставляют они сумрак (Г1), ветку (Г2) и глубины (Г3),
как в старину — чтобы слышать сладостную песнь

    того, что в лесах у Струмы
их держало тысячу веков. Вот сколько
владычествует моё горе и владычествовала его сладость!
```

---

**Добавление**: наверное, надо мне указать, что *вдохновило* этот странный вопрос. Это фраза из романа Пиранделло («Покойный Маттиа Паскаль»):

> Ma egli aveva una erudizione tutta sua particolare, curiosa e
>   bislacca. Era, per esempio, dottissimo in **bisticci**: conosceva la poesia fidenziana e la maccaronica, la burchiellesca e la leporeambica, e citava allitterazioni e annominazioni e **versi correlativi** e incatenati e retrogradi di tutti i poeti perdigiorni, e non poche rime balzane componeva egli stesso.

Эти слова – из характеристики одного персонажа, домашнего учителя. Примерно перевести можно так (если по смыслу прицепливаться к оригиналу):

> Но его эрудиция была весьма своеобразная – причудливая и нескладная. Он, например, очень хорошо был знаком с **барочным стихосложением**: знал поэзию фиденцианскую и макароническую, буркьелловскую и лепореамбическую, читал вслух аллитерации и анноминации, **стихи соотносительные**, цепочечные и анациклические всех самых разных поэтов-пустословов, и немало странных стихотворений он составил сам.

Впрочем, слово «bisticci» означает, скорее, шуточное стихосложение. Пиранделло приводит и пример такой шутки. Перевести этот пример на русский язык можно, скажем, так:

```
    Помню, как-то раз в «Сан Роккино» он сто раз, наверное,
заставил нас повторить вот это своё «Эхо», обращаясь к
холму напротив: 

     Кто украдкой погубит, бросит тело в овраг? 
                               — (Враг).
     Кто жестокой насмешкой поразит меня вдруг? 
                               — (Друг).
     Для кого мои слёзы – так, всего лишь потеха?
                               — (Эха).
```

В оригинале, правда, речь идёт о любви, да и эхо скорее сочувствует чтецу, чем насмехается над ним, но ведь неважно:

```
     In cuor di donna quanto dura amore?
                               — (Ore).
     Ed ella non mi amò quant'io l'amai?
                               — (Mai).
     Or chi sei tu che sì ti lagni meco?
                               — (Eco).
```

То есть:

```
     В сердце женском сколько длится любовь?
                               — (Пару часов).
     Она меня не любила, как я её любил?
                               — (Никогда).
     Но кто же ты – о, плачущий со мною?
                               — (Эхо).
```

Comment: Не могли бы вы привести небольшой пример такого стихотворения? Гугловый поиск выдаёт аж 140 статей по "correlative poetry" так что термин, прямо скажем, не очень известный. Цитата на испанском по ссылке - не лучший вариант.

Comment: Если бы я знал русский термин, то нашёл бы, конечно, и пример по-русски. :) Насколько я понимаю, это явление скорее историческое… Вот [тут](https://books.google.ru/books?id=vLp9BgAAQBAJ&pg=PA155&lpg=PA155&dq=%22correlative+poetry%22+examples&source=bl&ots=YgAxvuBijC&sig=a02CSPJ-HlOvBrpu9V123h2WUR8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiqmpPQz7vRAhVCdFAKHcNbCsUQ6AEILTAF#v=onepage&q=%22correlative%20poetry%22%20examples&f=false) пример двустишия, переведённого с древнегреческого на английский. Набор слов в стихе — это “plurality”…

Comment: Дело в том, что придумать-то термин — это не проблема. Коррелятивные, соотносительные… Но хотелось бы знать, есть ли в историческом стиховедении какие-нибудь устоявшиеся термины для такого рода «странных стихов»… Большое спасибо за внимание!

Comment: придумывать термины не так просто, термин может быть уже занять ;) -  есть, например, словосочетание "коррелятивная пара" - но она совсем про другое )

Comment: Сравнительно часто встречается термин "ассоциативная поэзия", но его толкуют более широко, чем пары слов и т. п.

Comment: А это сойдёт за A1-A3, B1-B3?
_Есть лукоморье, цепь и ветви, только жалко,
Что дуб не зелен, кот не учен, нет русалки._

Comment: @Alex_ander Если образовать из этого какое-нибудь смешное (интересное, забавное…) стихотворение и по-настоящему связать русалку с ветками (для меня связь не очевидна) – то, конечно, да. Если хотя бы одно из двух условий не выполнено – то нет.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, это некий вид **риторического параллелизма**: тождественного или сходного расположение элементов речи в смежных частях текста, которые, соотносясь, создают единый поэтический образ.

Comment: Спасибо, конечно, за предложение; но есть проблема: это название для широкого класса стилистических фигур. А меня интересует название для узкого жанра стихов. Схожее по классу название (как «чашка» — слово того же класса, что «вилка») — это «сонет». Но данный жанр, конечно, ещё уже… Собственно, в чём разница? (Которая именно меня интересует – не говорю, что это обязательно относится к приведённому примеру.) В том, что мы имеем корреляцию ради корреляции, а не ради того, чтобы выразить что-то более важное.

Comment: @Evgeniy вы и мне так говорили, но понимаете не всегда стихотворение с использованием определённого стилистического приёма имеет отдельное название. Иногда имеет, иногда нет - ну, хотя бы потому что может быть несколько использовано фигур. Так что если риторический параллелизм это действительно релевантный термин (я не знаю), то "стихотворение с использованием риторического параллелизма" - это как минимум один из возможных валидных ответов;

Comment: @shabunc Знаете, какой ответ я бы принял по-настоящему? Либо такой, который называет такой термин (с чем-нибудь, что я принял бы за, скажем так, доказательство…) – достаточно красивый, т. е. специфичный для данного случая. Либо такой, из которого мне понятно, что такого термина, скорее всего, в самом деле нет. Такие стихи – это, как я понимаю, маргинально важная часть старой западноевропейской культуры. Кто-то эту культуру изучает. У них либо есть такой термин, либо нет… Согласен: вопрос, наверное, слишком специальный для таких сайтов — это надо самому быть специалистом и идти в библиотеку…

Comment: @Evgeniy давайте ждать специалистов, просто я не удивлюсь если они скажут приблизительно то же самое что homocomputeris

Comment: @Evgeniy, может, напишу трюизм, но проще всего написать какому-нибудь преподавателю с кафедры романской филологии. Если даже и пошлёт, то, скорее всего, в верном направлении.

Comment: а лучше преподавателю с кафедры романском филологии сказать - смотри какой сайт есть, смотри какой там вопрос ;)